# set datasource for AutoCompleteStringCollection

Tags: c#, autocomplete, textbox

I try to use `AutoCompleteStringCollection` .So i use this code to do this :

```
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode=AutoCompleteMode.Append;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource; 

AutoCompleteStringCollection data = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

// Put here the auto completions' e.g. 
data.Add("My String 1");
data.Add("Autocompletion 2");
data.Add("Some stuff");

comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = data;
```

I add the value manually .i need to fetch my data from database using this code :

```
list<string> username=UserRepository.getall().select(i=>i.username).tolist();
```

How can i set the datasource of my **AutoCompleteStringCollection**  to **username**?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use a **addrange** method to do this :

```
  AutoCompleteStringCollection data = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            data.AddRange(objmemberRepository.GetAll().Select(i => i.username).ToArray());
```